# Highlight All Bookmarks in Word Doc Via VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word, highlight

I want to highlight all the bookmarks in my Word document. When I try to show the bookmarks, I only get the "I". And this code doesn't do anything.

Just like one of the commentators wrote, my bookmarks are 0 length. But even then how can I highlight say 2 spaces forward?

```
Sub BookMarks2Bold()
Dim bm As Bookmark
Dim tx As Range

Set tx = ActiveDocument.StoryRanges(wdMainTextStory)
For Each bm In tx.Bookmarks

    bm.Range.HighlightColorIndex = wdYellow
Next
```

End Sub

Comment: Probably because your bookmarks are "zero" length. In other words, you see the `Insert` cursor prompt at the bookmark point but to highlight something it needs at least one character. You're probably looking for a highlighted word or sentence. You will have to `Select` what you want highlighted beyond the bookmark point.

Answer (score 1):

If your bookmarks are zero range and you still want to highlight something in the document, you can extend the bookmark range, e.g. be the following character in the document:

```
Sub BookMarks2Bold()
    Dim bm As Bookmark
    Dim tx As Range
    dim rng as Range

    Set tx = ActiveDocument.StoryRanges(wdMainTextStory)
    For Each bm In tx.Bookmarks
        set rng = bm.Range
        rng.MoveEnd wdCharacter ' extend by one character

        ' optionally, expand by one word
        ' rng.Expand wdWord

        rng.HighlightColorIndex = wdYellow
    Next

End Sub
```